# Built-in web server floods syslog with request information

Tags: php, debian

I'm running php 8.3 cli on a debian 12.5 server.
The php process is spamming the debian syslog, with lots of access log for example:

```
Mar 14 14:19:38 *** php[***]: [Thu Mar 14 14:19:38 2024] ***:58391 Accepted
Mar 14 14:19:38 *** php[***]: [Thu Mar 14 14:19:38 2024] ***:58392 [200]: GET /***/***.php
Mar 14 14:19:38 *** php[***]: [Thu Mar 14 14:19:38 2024] ***:58392 Closing
Mar 14 14:19:45 *** php[***]: [Thu Mar 14 14:19:45 2024] ***:58401 Accepted
Mar 14 14:19:46 *** php[***]: [Thu Mar 14 14:19:46 2024] ***:58401 [200]: POST /***/***.php
Mar 14 14:19:46 *** php[***]: [Thu Mar 14 14:19:46 2024] ***:58401 Closing
Mar 14 14:19:46 *** php[***]: [Thu Mar 14 14:19:46 2024] ***:58403 Accepted
Mar 14 14:19:47 *** php[***]: [Thu Mar 14 14:19:47 2024] ***:58403 [200]: POST /***/***.php
Mar 14 14:19:47 *** php[***]: [Thu Mar 14 14:19:47 2024] ***:58403 Closing
```

No matter what configuration I did in the php.ini file (including disabling all error logs), will not stop the access log.
The HTTP server is the one built-in PHP 8.3, no external webserver is used.

I found some configuration for it in OLD php versions, but they do not work for php 8.3

If anyone could help me disabling this output to the system logs, I would appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you certain that you are editing the CLI ini files, and not CGI or FPM ones?

Comment: Yes, I verified its location using phpinfo, and also saw the change afterwards in the phpinfo.

Comment: PHP by itself does not really log anything but errors, and these are activity logs written by some HTTP based application. I can't tell for sure that it isn't some PHP handler but it's certainly not CLI interpreter the one to blame. I'd start by finding out what web application is hosted in your machine and continue from there.

Comment: Thank you @ÁlvaroGonzález, I'm using the HTTP server that is built-in PHP 8.3

Comment: How are you running the builtin web server? Do you type the command in a terminal, or you've built some kind of automation?

Comment: I don't think you can disable those logs from the built-in web server. It's for development, don't use it in production.

Comment: Note it just dumps all this output to stderr though, so you can do `php -S <whatever> 2>/dev/null` to just throw it all away. But you shouldn't do that. Use php-fpm fronted by an actual web server like nginx.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, I'm running it as a system service.

Comment: You should be able to specify how stderr is treated in the service definition.

Comment: `StandardError=null` in the service file.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, It's one of the things I tried. It works well when running from ssh, but when using this command line as a service, the service is running, but the http server doesn't work (no errors in syslog).

Comment: Well, of course, if you send output to null, it'll be _all_ output, including the output that you actually want to keep... like errors. That's one of the many reasons you shouldn't use this in production.

Comment: @Barmar,  PERFECT. Together with AlexHowansky (stderr), it solved it. Thank you both so much. I couldn't find out where to mark a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try redirecting the output of the PHP -S command to `/dev/null` if you don't care about it at all:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8181 &> /dev/null
```

Bear in mind, you shouldn't be using the PHP builtin service in production, it's only really intended for development purposes, you should use something like apache2 or nginx for your live server.

From the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

> Warning
> This web server is designed to aid application development. It
> may also be useful for testing purposes or for application
> demonstrations that are run in controlled environments. It is not
> intended to be a full-featured web server. It should not be used on a
> public network.

Comment: ITYM "shouldn't"

Comment: Also, as @Barmar said, if executed as a service the syntax is StandardError=null